# How to get href of links inside div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please, help, I try to get href of links inside div using jquery, but unfortunatelly, it doesn`t work.

Here is my page, where I dynamically get other divs(inside them links are located) inside #films

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cinemas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <div id = "films"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get(myUrl, function(data) { // this block works
    $('#films').html($('.block_afisha', data).html())
    });

    $('#films').find('a').each(function() { // there is no iterations here
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: This is a async operation. Your links are added asynchronously and you are finding them so it is not necessary that the links present when you find them as the async operation is still in progress.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get(myUrl, function(data) { // this block works - async block
        $('#films').html($('.block_afisha', data).html()); 

        $('#films').find('a').each(function() { // this will work if above call has added links with anchor tag
             console.log($(this).attr('href'));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @Nico_99 please accept answer if it works as expected, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just load the links and then iterate through them:

```
<div id="elems">
<a href="#one">One</a>
<a href="#two">Two</a>
<a href="#three">Three</a>
</div>

$.each($('#elems > a'),function(data,value){
console.log($(value).attr('href'));
});
```